# How to use Ext.create properly

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

Can't find any relevant information in the sencha documention about this question :

Is it possible to call `Ext.create(...)` with a parameter which does not depend on the application's name?
So that if I change the app's name I don't have to rewrite that line of code?

Normally I would use `Ext.create(AppName.model.MYMODEL)` but that's too tied to the app's name for me.

Still need help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Create using class alias

When using `Ext.define` to define your class, you can provide an `alias` property. You've probably seen this on UI components which use aliases like `widget.panel`. Those aliases can be used with `Ext.create`.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.SomeClass', {
    alias: 'app.someclass',  // Independent of class name
    /* ... */
});

Ext.create('app.someclass', {
    /* ... */
});
```

You can set the alias on a class after it has been created by using `Ext.ClassManager.setAlias`.

### Helper function using application name

If you don't have the option to set an alias, you could create a function that wraps `Ext.create` which supplies your base namespace automatically.

The problem here is that `Ext.application` doesn't return the application object. I'm not sure how Sencha Architect generates the application code but you may need additional overrides to allow you to retrieve the application object.

```
function appCreate(className, config) {
    var appName = someMethodThatGetsTheApplicationName();
    return Ext.create(appName + '.' + className, config);
};

// Example usage: Creates object of MyApp.model.MyModel
var myObj = appCreate('model.MyModel', { /* ... */ });
```

### How to get the application name at runtime

By default, Ext JS does not retain a reference to the application object when using `Ext.application`, so we need an override to do it. I'm using `Ext.currentApp` as the property to store this object, but you can change it to whatever you'd like.

```
Ext.application = function (config) {
    Ext.require('Ext.app.Application');

    Ext.onReady(function () {
        Ext.currentApp = new Ext.app.Application(config);
    });
};
```

Now that you have this, you can access the application name by simply using `Ext.currentApp.name`. Or, if you'd feel more comfortable using a getter you can use the following.

```
Ext.app.Application.addMembers({
    getName: function () {
        return this.name;
    }
});

// Example usage:
function someMethodThatGetsTheApplicationName() {
    if (!Ext.currentApp) {
        Ext.Error.raise('Current app does not exist.');
    }
    return Ext.currentApp.getName();
}
```

Comment: You kind of found what I need without having it :p
the Somemethodthatgetstheapplicationname() woudld be pretty damn useful.

Comment: Well documented answer but it is longer and more complicated than the one I just found.Is there something wrong with min, you seem to know alot.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use any class name in `Ext.create` there is no naming convention imposed there as long as the class was already defined. If you want `Ext.create` to load the correct file using `Ext.loader` you will need to configure the loader to conform with the naming convention you need.

Comment: Could you give me more details, not quite sure to follow.

I have used Ext.define, Ext.loader yet so you kind of lost me there XD

Comment: Sure, how do you usually define your classes?

Comment: Actually, I'm using Sencha Architect, so I guess my models are defined automaticly by it. I just set the fields and the property through UI of Architect, not really coding it except for function in my model.
Might help a bit, I missed a word in my previous comment I haven't used Ext.define,  Ext loader yet (manually).

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about Architect.. Maybe repost the question and tag it with sencha-architect.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do it :

You need a controller that will in it's **INIT function** (before UI Loading/Initiating) do the following

```
APPNAME = this.getApplication().getName();
```

Where APPNAME is a global variable.

Then when you Ext.create something you will be able to write the following

```
Ext.create(APPNAME +'model.MyModel');
```

That way you can change you app name without having to check everywhere in your code to change every single Ext.create to the new app's name.

It also give you the ability if you are to use this.getApplication().setName() to have infinite cache storage has you get 5/10mb per AppName.